# What can happen if I accidentally paste into command mode? What should I do if I do this?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, undo-redo

If I have vim in a windowed terminal, sometimes I paste (using the terminal's paste functionality, e.g. middle click) from another window that isn't vim. Most of the time, when I do this, I wanted to be in insert mode.

Obviously, this mistake can basically do anything that vim can do; most of the time there will be an early insert-mode character that will prevent most forms of document damage.

What's the best way to recover from this mistake?

Comment: In case of you didn't know about 'u' - undo.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that no `:w` or `:write` command was issued, all of the changes should still be in the buffer only, not written to disk.

An `:earlier 30s` command should restore your buffer to the state it was in 30 seconds ago.

Of course, if you want to discard all changes, there's always `:quit!`.

Comment: If `:w` did happen, will `:earlier 30s` still work?

Comment: `:earlier 30s` restores the buffer to the state it was in 30 seconds ago. After reverting, you would then have to save it using `:w`.